# How to exclude files when IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract is used?

Tags: .net, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a Console app that is using PowerShell SDK. The SDK produces additional directories (ref,runtimes) when building app. The folders ref and runtime are part of NuGet Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK - [List of NuGet Package Folders/Files](https://nuget.info/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/7.3.3). I can remove those directories when I'm building the app by using custom target aka `<Target Name="CustomAfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build">`.

I want to get rid of them for the single-file executable. I've tried "Before/AfterTargets" for "Build", "Publish", "BeforePublish", "BeforeBuild", "PrepareForPublish", "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems", "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" etc

But this doesn't work when I'm usingIncludeAllContentForSelfExtract. The directory of the extracted app located in `Temp\.net\ConsolePowerShellSDKApp` still has those folders.

Does `ExcludeFromSingleFile` or anything else cover the scenario of excluding files from a single-file executable that is actually part of NuGet package?

Example: https://github.com/ALIENQuake/ConsolePowerShellSDKApp

ConsolePowerShellSDKApp.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <DelCmd Condition="&apos;$(OS)&apos; == &apos;Windows_NT&apos;">rmdir /S /Q</DelCmd>
    <DirCmd Condition="&apos;$(OS)&apos; == &apos;Windows_NT&apos;">dir</DirCmd>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomAfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="CustomAfterBuild - AfterTargets - Build" Importance="High"/>
    <Exec Command="$(DelCmd) &quot;$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)ref&quot;"/>
    <Exec Command="$(DelCmd) &quot;$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)runtimes&quot;"/>
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="7.4.0-preview.1"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

ConsolePowerShellSDKApp.cs

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using Microsoft.PowerShell;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
//string AppDir = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ? Path.GetFullPath(AppContext.BaseDirectory) : Environment.CurrentDirectory;

var runspaceConfiguration = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows() == true)
{
    runspaceConfiguration.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.Bypass;
}
var pipeline = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration));

pipeline.Runspace.Open();
pipeline.Commands.AddCommand("Get-ChildItem");

var results = pipeline.Invoke();
foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Console.WriteLine(@"Press any key.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I've tried every After/Before Targets:

```
AfterTargets="AfterBuild"
AfterTargets="Build"
BeforeTargets="Publish"
BeforeTargets="BeforePublish"
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of dotnet guys, I did it! Use Regex.IsMatch instead of Contains because you can use slashes.

This is the 'Target' definition:

```
<Target Name="Custom_Before_GenerateSingleFileBundle_DependsOn_PrepareForBundle" BeforeTargets="GenerateSingleFileBundle" DependsOnTargets="PrepareForBundle">
  <ItemGroup>
  <FilesToBundle 
        Remove="@(_FilesToBundle)"

        Condition=
        "
            $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch(%(_FilesToBundle.RelativePath), &quot;ref\\&quot;))
            OR
            $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch(%(_FilesToBundle.RelativePath), &quot;runtimes\\&quot;))
        "
        />
</ItemGroup>
<Message Importance="High" Text="%(_FilesToBundle.RelativePath)"/>
<Message Importance="High" Text="@(FilesToBundle)"/>
```

Additional info:
https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2021/before_bundle_build_hook.md

https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/18a8e986ddf28ee3c950b5acf00abc652d87be74/src/Tools/Directory.Build.targets

https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/ead8e64b26de75a0dd098111b643f5151913e4ce/docs/core/deploying/single-file/overview.md

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can

Add the code below to your .csproj file

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="ref\**\*;runtimes\**\*">
    <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It didn't help, the single-file extraction directory "...\Temp\.net\ConsolePowerShellSDKApp\nIx0HekWgxIYT2Ggx89OsOwz9X3UCrQ=\" still contain 'runtimes' and 'ref' folders.